# RSS: Difference between active and newest questions

Tags: support, rss

I'm subscribed to TeX.SX RSS for several tags. In fact I'm subscribed to `newest questions` and `active questions`. The problem is that I don't see to much difference between these categories. I was thinking that an active question is a question which shows 'some activity' (new answers) after being 'new question', but my feeds reader (Opera) shows all new questions in both lists and only when a new answer (some times also an edition) for a very old question arrives to tex.sx, it announces it.

As a recent example, yesterday I received the feed about [One navigation bullet per subsection with subsection=false in custom beamer theme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64333/one-navigation-bullet-per-subsection-with-subsection-false-in-custom-beamer-them). It was shown in `newest questions tagged beamer` and `active questions tagged beamer`.
After several hours without any answer diabonas wrote one but I've not received any announce about it. Why?

Due to the delay between tex.sx and my feeds reader, most of new questions are already answered (you are too fast!) when I read them but some other not and I would like to know when them are solved  without marking each particular question. Is it possible? How?